# No Internet access using ad hoc network in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I setup a wifi Hotspot in my desktop(Ubuntu 12.04), and was able to connect to it using my laptop(also Ubuntu 12.04).

My desktop is connected to Internet using Ethernet cable and I can access internet from my desktop but not from my laptop.

Also I can ping successfully to my router from my laptop, but still no internet.

Please point me how to troubleshoot this.

Desktop routing table.

```
$ /sbin/route -n

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: can you please check DNS and gateway settings on your laptop? I think the desktop pc assign them (DHCP) to your laptop.

Comment: Laptop DNS: 10.42.0.1, Gateway: 10.42.0.1.
10.42.0.1 is the ip address of my wifi card in the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is only part of the problem. check this documentation on Internet connection sharing in ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing 
it will require DNSMasq and some IPTables configuration, or you can do it through the NetworkManager gui. Note that per the documentation, ICS for Adhoc wireless does not support WPA, so you have to rely on WEP.

Comment: WPA is supported in Ubuntu 12.10 though.

Comment: ok good. hopefully some day someone will update the documentation.